# Optimizing Ruby Arrays or Hashes

Tags: ruby

I have a program that produces simulated typing. The program takes user input on where the location of the file is and the file along with the extension. It then breaks down the file using an iteration and puts it into an array.

```
def file_to_array(file)
  empty = []
  File.foreach("#{file}") do |line|
    empty << line.to_s.split('')
  end
  return empty.flatten!
end
```

When the program runs, it sends the keys to the text area to simulate typing via `win32ole`.

After 5,000 characters there's too much memory overhead and the program begins to slow down. The further past 5,000 characters, the slower it goes. Is there a way that this can be optimized?

--EDIT--

```
require 'Benchmark'

def file_to_array(file)
  empty = []
  File.foreach(file) do |line|
    empty << line.to_s.split('')
  end
  return empty.flatten!
end
def file_to_array_2(file)
  File.read(file).split('')
end

file = 'xxx'

Benchmark.bm do |results|
    results.report { print file_to_array(file) }
    results.report { print file_to_array_2(file) }
end
    user     system      total        real
 0.234000   0.000000   0.234000 (  0.787020)
 0.218000   0.000000   0.218000 (  1.917185)
```

Comment: Am I undestanding correctly -- the array `empty` stores one character per element?  Have you considered just storing the text, and iterating through it using `each_char`?  (Or, not storing it at all, but leaving it in the fle...?)

Comment: I wrote an alternative method using such a method based on @Aetherus's suggestions but when I tested it, the memory began to cap out at around 7,000 characters and thus the program began to slow down. The method that I am currently using in this code snippet slows down at around 5,000 characters. It's an improvement, but not enough. Through what I've looked it for optimization, I did manage to cut down the system stress by half. You can look at the full code here.  https://github.com/sinithwar/LazyProjects/blob/master/RubyTypingSim.rb

Answer (score 2):

I did my benchmark and profile, here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'benchmark'
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-prof'

def ftoa_1(path)
  empty = []
  File.foreach(path) do |line|
    empty << line.to_s.split('')
  end
  return empty.flatten!
end

def ftoa_2(path)
  File.read(path).split('')
end

def ftoa_3(path)
  File.read(path).chars
end

def ftoa_4(path)
  File.open(path) { |f| f.each_char.to_a }
end

GC.start
GC.disable

Benchmark.bm(6) do |x|
  1.upto(4) do |n|
    x.report("ftoa_#{n}") {send("ftoa_#{n}", ARGV[0])}
  end
end

1.upto(4) do |n|
  puts "\nProfiling ftoa_#{n} ...\n"

  result = RubyProf.profile do
    send("ftoa_#{n}", ARGV[0])
  end

  RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(result).print($stdout)
end
```

And here is my result:

```
             user     system      total        real
ftoa_1   2.090000   0.160000   2.250000 (  2.250350)
ftoa_2   1.540000   0.090000   1.630000 (  1.632173)
ftoa_3   0.420000   0.080000   0.500000 (  0.505286)
ftoa_4   0.550000   0.090000   0.640000 (  0.630003)

Profiling ftoa_1 ...
Measure Mode: wall_time
Thread ID: 70190654290440
Fiber ID: 70189795562220
Total: 2.571306
Sort by: self_time

 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 83.39      2.144     2.144     0.000     0.000   103930   String#split
 12.52      0.322     0.322     0.000     0.000        1   Array#flatten!
  3.52      2.249     0.090     0.000     2.159        1   <Class::IO>#foreach
  0.57      0.015     0.015     0.000     0.000   103930   String#to_s
  0.00      2.571     0.000     0.000     2.571        1   Global#[No method]
  0.00      2.571     0.000     0.000     2.571        1   Object#ftoa_1
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Fixnum#to_s

* indicates recursively called methods

Profiling ftoa_2 ...
Measure Mode: wall_time
Thread ID: 70190654290440
Fiber ID: 70189795562220
Total: 1.855242
Sort by: self_time

 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 99.77      1.851     1.851     0.000     0.000        1   String#split
  0.23      0.004     0.004     0.000     0.000        1   <Class::IO>#read
  0.00      1.855     0.000     0.000     1.855        1   Global#[No method]
  0.00      1.855     0.000     0.000     1.855        1   Object#ftoa_2
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Fixnum#to_s

* indicates recursively called methods

Profiling ftoa_3 ...
Measure Mode: wall_time
Thread ID: 70190654290440
Fiber ID: 70189795562220
Total: 0.721246
Sort by: self_time

 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 99.42      0.717     0.717     0.000     0.000        1   String#chars
  0.58      0.004     0.004     0.000     0.000        1   <Class::IO>#read
  0.00      0.721     0.000     0.000     0.721        1   Object#ftoa_3
  0.00      0.721     0.000     0.000     0.721        1   Global#[No method]
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Fixnum#to_s

* indicates recursively called methods

Profiling ftoa_4 ...
Measure Mode: wall_time
Thread ID: 70190654290440
Fiber ID: 70189795562220
Total: 0.816140
Sort by: self_time

 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 99.99      0.816     0.816     0.000     0.000        2   IO#each_char
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   File#initialize
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   IO#close
  0.00      0.816     0.000     0.000     0.816        1   <Class::IO>#open
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   IO#closed?
  0.00      0.816     0.000     0.000     0.816        1   Global#[No method]
  0.00      0.816     0.000     0.000     0.816        1   Enumerable#to_a
  0.00      0.816     0.000     0.000     0.816        1   Enumerator#each
  0.00      0.816     0.000     0.000     0.816        1   Object#ftoa_4
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Fixnum#to_s

* indicates recursively called methods
```

The conclusion is that `ftoa_3` is the fastest when GC is turned off, but I would recommend `ftoa_4` because it uses less memory and thus reduces the times of GC. If you turn GC on, you can see `ftoa_4` will be the fastest.

From the profile result, you can see the program spends most time in `String#split` in both `ftoa_1` and `ftoa_2`. The `ftoa_1` is the worst because `String#split` runs many times (1 for each line), and `Array.flatten!` also takes a lot of time.

Comment: Would it be faster still if it were turned into a hash?

Comment: Then what will be the keys and what will be the values?

Comment: The values would be the characters in the array and the keys would be incremented numbers from 0. I only ask this because I have read that hashes are best for massive linear searches.

Comment: Nothing is faster than accessing the elements in arrays by index. Although searching by key in a hash also takes (typically) O(1) time, it involves a call to `hash_code` of the key and thus is slower than searching by index in an array.

Comment: Ahh okay. :) Thank you very much. Oh, and what about map? Would that be useful as well or is to_a faster?

Comment: And a hash requires at lease 4/3 times more memory than an array of the same size.

Comment: `Enumerable#map` internally uses `each` and performes a block call in every iteration, thus is slower than `to_a`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Okay, still needs some more work in optimization, but you gave it one heck of a push. It seems that GC is asking for more memory from the IO and this is what is causing the slowdown. Would breaking the big array down into smaller arrays prevent this or lessen this?

Comment: A bunch of small arrays will only ask more memory if you keep them all in memory. If you can read some chars, output them, throw them away and read some more chars, then it will be much more memory efficient.

Comment: Would I use `array.shift` to throw them away?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108746/discussion-between-aetherus-and-tommy-mertell).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be optimized (written sorter, with less assignments and less method calls):

```
def file_to_array(file)
  File.read(file).split('')
end
```

This works, because `file` is already a string and therefore there is no need for the string interpolation `"#{file}"`. `File.read` returns the whole file, this removes the need to iterate over each line. Without the iteration there is no need for a temporary `empty` array, the `flatten!` and the string concatenation `<<`. And there is no need for the explizit `return` in your example.

---

**Update**: It is not clear from your question what you are optimizing for: performance, memory usage or readablity. Since I was surprised by your benchmark results I ran my own. And I think my solution is faster than yours.

But the results might differ on different Ruby versions (I used Ruby 2.3), the input file size and number of lines or the number of iterations ran in the benchmark.

```
def file_to_array_1(file)
  empty = []
  File.foreach("#{file}") do |line|
    empty << line.to_s.split('')
  end
  return empty.flatten!
end

def file_to_array_2(file)
  File.read(file).split('')
end

require 'benchmark'

# file = '...' # a path to a file with about 26KB data in about 750 lines
n = 1000

Benchmark.bmbm(15) do |x|
  x.report("version 1 :")   { n.times do; file_to_array_1(file); end }
  x.report("version 2 :")   { n.times do; file_to_array_2(file); end }
end

# Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------
# version 1 :      11.970000   0.110000  12.080000 ( 12.092841)
# version 2 :       8.150000   0.120000   8.270000 (  8.267420)
# ----------------------------------------- total: 20.350000sec

#                       user     system      total        real
# version 1 :      11.940000   0.100000  12.040000 ( 12.045505)
# version 2 :       8.130000   0.110000   8.240000 (  8.248707)
# [Finished in 40.7s]
```

Comment: Thank you :) this was an excellent answer and I will test it out immediately as I wait for more suggestions.

Comment: Okay, but I need it to be a container in order to iterate over the container to send the keys to the file. Will this also save it to a container for later use or should I put it into a variable and return the variable for local use?

Comment: I have tested it and it is actually slower than my method.

http://pastebin.com/SWQHV6nY

Comment: What do you mean by *container*? My answer returns exactly the same as your example (an array containing all chars of the file). Is doesn't make a difference to the caller of the method when you assign the array to a local variable before returning it to the caller. It makes a difference when you assign it to an instance variable. But your example doesn't use instance variables.

Comment: I have updated the pastbin to show you how I tested the code. I substituted the SendKeys method with print in order to have a faster result. The code shows that it takes almost 2 1/2 times longer for your method than my method. Or am I using it wrong?

Comment: The program I am using sends keys to a text file while one maybe records it. This is to simulate typing. After 5,000 characters there's too much memory overhead and the program begins to slow down. That is the part I'm trying to optimize. The file I am testing on has 180,000 characters. Since I have to have it send the keys via iteration, I want to see if I can optimize the array so that it will use less memory. Therefore, yes, building the array is faster but iterating over it via the print method was slower.

Comment: I updated my answer. To run a benchmark only once might lead to imprecise results, when the number just too small. What do you mean by `SendKeys` method and `print`, I don't find these in your question nor your pastebin. Btw: can you please copy your pastebin to your question. That makes it easier to other readers in the future to find and understand this question and answers.

Comment: Why do you store the characters in a temporarily array and don't send them directly when you read the file? Direct sending would reduce the memory usage, because you do not need to store the file in memory.

Comment: Okay, so the SendKeys method sends a command to the keyboard handler to simulate human typing. So like, to do " it would need to `SendKeys("+{'}")`. Therefore, it has to be iterative. The array, even when I tested it with the print method, takes up too much memory overhead.

Comment: I would try `File.new(filename).each_char { |c| SendKeys(c) }` to reduce memory usage.

Comment: Also consider using `#chars` instead of `#split('')`, or even better, `#each_char` if possible in your benchmarks.